# How to do shared library in tomcat version 6.0 in Linux environment?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a two application webapp1 and webapp2. Both application use the same library zx.jar.
Now i have put the jar in two location `/webapp1/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` and `/webapp2/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib`

But I don't want to load jar twice. I want to use the jar `/tomcat/lib` ?

How can I implement this in Linux environment?

Comment: put it in catalina_home/lib/, it will be shared by all webapps

Answer (score 2):

Put your library at below location

```
•Tomcat 6 $CATALINA_HOME/lib   
•Tomcat 5 $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib
```

More info [Apache ClassLoader Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

Comment: i have put in my jar $CATALINA_HOME/lib  here . But its not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your `jar` in the in the tomcat lib folder (`$CATALINA_HOME/lib`).

And if you are using [maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) as build tool, just put `<scope>provided</scope>` in the dependency of the corresponding jar!

And if you are using [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) to build, just make sure that, you don't copy the `jar` to the deployed application's lib folder, while building and deploying your application.

Comment: I am build the jar using Ant tool, and deployed to tomcat/lib ..But its not work . Any other way to do?

Answer (score 0):

With Tomcat 6, "common" JARs to be shared between multiple servlets should be placed in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` or `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.  It is documented in the [Apache 6 - Classloader HOW TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) document.

However you need to be careful when you do this because:

- "common" JARS and other files / directories in the `lib` directories take precedence over stuff in each webapp,
- any static variables in "common" classes are actually visible to all webapps, and
- leakage of types from one webapp to another can cause strange problems; e.g. type casts failing unexpectedly.

Comment: I think there is typo in your post after **or**.

Comment: i have put the jar in tomcat/lib but unable to work my application